# How do I bring a kill window to the front in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, stack, window

I have a python program that opens up in full screen. In the program window is a button that the user is supposed to use when they want to exit the program. This is the function for when they click the button:

```
def closeProgram():
    file_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    file = open("SaveFile1.txt", "a")
    file.write(file_name)
    file.close()
    exit()
```

But when I call the exit() function, the kill window that pops up, asking if I REALLY want to stop the program, shows up underneath the program window. Is there way a to bring the kill window to the front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by IDLE, not by python or tkinter. Use `raise SystemExit` instead to kill only your program and not IDLE. Or (much better) redesign your program so that it reaches the end when done. If you are using a tkinter mainloop you can use `root.quit()` to end it.